# jqGrid - destroyfrozenColumns and sorting stop working

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqGrid which has sorting on all columns. I then freeze a column using a menu item. I then unfreeze the grid using destroyFrozenColumns and called reload, The sorting on the grid has stopped working. What could that be?

Comment: When exactly does sorting stop working? Can you still sort after freezing a column?

Comment: When you freeze a column then the sorting on any column which was sortable stops working.

Answer (score 0):

According to jQgrid's documentation and forum you cannot use frozen columns and sorting at the same time, so I suppose that if you are using one of the features, the other one becomes disabled no matter if you call "destroyFrozenColumns". I debugged frozen columns and it seems that the way this feature works is - it is creating a second table on top of the main one with the column you chose as frozen ones. So you cannot make a synchronized sorting between your table and the one that is dynamically created when you use frozen columns.
To your question: my guess is that the second dynamically created table remains even if you use "destroyFrozenColumns".